# Rendering trouble when transfering my django project on vps

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, webserver

I have developped my django project, in my localhost environnement everything is working like it is supposed to be.

When I send it over my vps (straight copy paste over ftp) and launch my server there is a problem with rendering some parts of my website.
(especially the backend using sbadmin2)

I attach the two version when it look ok it is on localhost and the other are the online version.

I have really no idea what is happening and where to look at.

[image: Login page]
[image: vps login login]
[image: localhost page]
[image: vps page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I feel really bad for this one,
I have checked again and after a night thinking and going deep in the code I realize that my template share sometimes the same name of css and js file (bootstrap.css for example)
So i decided to redo all the link to the right static file so i don't have anymore shared file between the front and the back end and voila it solved my problem.

Thank xjtian for having taking time to help me really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to collect static files. On your server, assuming you've got `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` configured correctly in your project settings module, run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will gather all of the static files that you've written and ones specific to 3rd party apps you've installed in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory. You're also going to have to configure your webserver to serve these files directly. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deployment and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/ for more information.

If you're using Apache, you can just `Alias` to your static root directory. For example, if your `STATIC_URL` setting is `'/static/'` and your `STATIC_ROOT` is set to `'/home/user/example.com/mysite/static/'`, you would include the following snippet in your Apache configuration:

```
Alias /static/ /home/user/example.com/mysite/static/
<Directory /home/user/example.com/mysite/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi xjtian, the thing is the frontpage and other page that are not related to sbadmin do show like they should and not the one with sbadmin files I am gonna try with your solution too, i am using nginx server